# "Too many opened conversations. Please close them and try again."

Tags: multithreading, mulesoft

When accessing my application on mulesoft, I am getting the following error:

```
Message               : 42|Application|Too many opened conversations. Please close them and try again.
Element               : null @ my-application-1:null:null
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
42|Application|Too many opened conversations. Please close them and try again. (org.mule.module.ws.consumer.SoapFaultException)
  org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.unmarshalFault(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:84)
  org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:51)
  org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.Soap11FaultInInterceptor.handleMessage(Soap11FaultInInterceptor.java:40)
  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
  org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.onMessage(AbstractFaultChainInitiatorObserver.java:113)
  org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:69)
  org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.CheckFaultInterceptor.handleMessage(CheckFaultInterceptor.java:34)
  org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
  org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.onMessage(ClientImpl.java:856)
  org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.sendResultBackToCxf(MuleUniversalConduit.java:359)
  org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit.dispatchMuleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:316)
  org.mule.module.cxf.transport.MuleUniversalConduit$2.handleMessage(MuleUniversalConduit.java:223)
  (227 more...)

  (set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)
```

I am not sure where the error originates, is it because some limitation on the backend server, or should I look into internal limitations like "maxThreads"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a SOAP fault is being received from remote web service. The description `42|Application|Too many opened conversations. Please close them and try again.` seems to be sent by the web service and doesn't look to be generated by Mule.